# How to place iteration index into array index using thymeleaf?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to iterate over list with keeping track of iteration and I want to place iteration index into array index of that list:

What I tried:

```
<tr th:each="experience, iter : *{experiences}">
    <td>Experience name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{experiences[iter.index]}" value="${experience.name}">
</tr>
```

Here I get `NumberFormatException`. So I tried to use `$`, because I think that `iter` is a variable:

```
<tr th:each="experience, iter : *{experiences}">
    <td>Experience name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{experiences[${iter.index}]}" value="${experience.name}">
</tr>
```

Here, `${iter.index}` is not evaluated, so I get error that `${iter.index}` is not a number (again `NumberFormatException`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `iter.index` using 2 underscores.

```java
<tr th:each="experience, iter : *{experiences}">
    <td>Experience name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{experiences[__${iter.index}__]}" />
</tr>
```

`__${...}__` syntax is a preprocessing expression, which is an inner expression that is evaluated before actually evaluating the whole expression. https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#preprocessing